# Normal maps Problems

Tags: modeling, normals

well after some time of breaking my head trying to figure out what im doing wrong, i decided to ask.
here is the blend file with my different "try's", i just dont know what im doing wrong, every single one has an artifact or a seam, etc

[image]

all where baked with xnormal, 1024x1024 8 edge padding 4xaa.

the blend consist of different cubes, a standard one, a bevel one, and a bevel one with a bit more details. (also seam,noseam,sharp, i just had to try every single method..) also the normals are packed in.

well hopefully i could get some help. here is the result of the normals, you can find more into the blend (different try's in different layers)
[image: Different Normal Attempt]
[image]

hopefully i can get some help, long time breaking my head with this, sometimes it works with more complex objects, but now i cant even do a simple cube.

Bye!

Comment: Oh dear! you already broke your head? I usually ask *before* I get to [this point](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WnrOk.gif)

Comment: Hmmm ... don't seems to get what sort of issues you are having with the seams but it all seems alright to me. You mind adding a red circle on the area with issues?

Comment: sure, added, also if u open the file u can check from different angles, i just dont know what method to use, if the sharp are used correctly, the difference beetwhen seams and no seams.. (mb my eyes are tricking me)